# SQL Server Service Broker - Group By User Request

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I am prototyping usage of SQL Server Service Broker to process queued items. Thus far things are going well.

One thing that I would like to do is to be able to process several items from the queue in parallel on different processes or threads, but limit processing so that a particular user can only have one item processed at a time, to prevent one overzealous user from starving out all others.

The processing on parallel threads is easy. The limiting per user is not so straightforward. Initially I thought I could set the conversation group id to the id of the user, and therefore have processing of the group be serialized automatically by the service broker. At this point, I have not found a way to implement this option successfully.

Is this something that can be done with conversation groups? Is there a simpler way with or without the service broker? Am I going to have to take care of it outside of the service broker?

I have done quite a bit of research, but it's all starting to run together, so apologies if I missed something obvious.

Comment: Can you explain what you're queueing?  It will matter for the person answering as service broker implementations can vary greatly.  I've built them in the past so that triggers queued PK ids into a service broker queue table, moving a prioritization value up and down based on business logic.  Then on the other side, service broker wakes up, pulls a batch of items from the queue table in sorted order by prioritization and does the required work.  It's not too difficult, but is very situational (hence the request for more details).

Comment: Interesting. Yes, I'm queuing PK ids. Hadn't thought about using priority. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 1):

As you have hinted, you can have a one-one relationship between conversations and users and then, through the magic of conversation group locking, SSSB will only process one thing at a time for each user.

The system generates id's for conversations itself so you can't set them, but you could use a table that maps users to conversations.

Comment: I spent an entire day trying to lock on conversation group. Had problems with group not transferring to the target side, so I tried moving the group. That didn't work, so I tried a suggestion of reversing the from target to initiator, but that didn't work out. At this point, setting priority looks like the winner.

Comment: The locking is implicit, you shouldn't have to do do anything to make it work. Whenever a queue processor successfully reads from a queue, that conversation group is then locked so other processors cannot read its messages.

Comment: `reversing the from target to initiator, but that didn't work out`: generally, that's the solution. Can you explain why it didn't work out?

Comment: @RemusRusanu, I'm guessing that I am just doing it wrong, as far as reversing the flow. I haven't found a good, simple example on exactly what reversing the flow involves. For now, using priority works, but I expect that there's a good chance we'll want to revisit it before too long.